# How to extract string between key substring and "/" with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that's

```
/path/to/file?_subject_ID_SOMEOTHERSTRING
```

the path/to/file part changes depends on situation, and `subject_ID` is always there. I try to write a regex that extract only `file` part of the string. Using `?subject_ID` is definite, but I don't know how to safely get the `file`

My current regex looks like `(.*[\/]).*\?_subject_ID`

```
url = '/path/to/file?_subject_ID_SOMEOTHERSTRING'
file_re = re.compile('(.*[\/]).*\?_subject_ID')
file_re.search(url)
```

this will find the right string, but I still can't extract the file name

printing _.group(1) will get me `/path/to/`. What's the next step that gets me the actual file name?

Comment: Using your approach: [`r'.*/(.*)\?_subject_ID'`](https://regex101.com/r/uU3vH7/1) and access with `group(1)`

Comment: Uh, are you sure that example string is accurate?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes fixed it. it should work now

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew group(1) gets my `/path/to/`, should I use the index of this substring and of `?_subject_ID`?

Comment: Use http://ideone.com/mCTTyQ

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah...that's a smart idea..... please reply to the post and I'll mark it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your `'(.*[\/]).*\?_subject_ID'` regex approach, you just need to add a capturing group around the second `.*`. You could use [`r'(.*/)(.*)\?_subject_ID'`](https://regex101.com/r/uU3vH7/1) (then, there will be `.group(1)` and `.group(2)` parts captured), but it is not the most appropriate way to parse URLs in Python.

You may use the non-regex approach here, here is a snippet showing how to leverage `urlparse` and `os.path` to parse the URL like yours:

```
import urlparse
path = urlparse.urlparse('/path/to/file?_subject_ID_SOMEOTHERSTRING').path
import os.path
print(os.path.split(path)[1]) # => file
print(os.path.split(path)[0]) # => /path/to
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/mCTTyQ)

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple, really. Just match a `/` before and `?subject_ID` after:

```
([^/?]*)\?subject_ID
```

The `[^/?]*` (as opposed to `.*`) is because otherwise it'd match the part before, too. The `?` in the character class

If you want to get both the path and the file, you can do much the same thing, but also grab the part before the `/`:

```
([^?]*)([^/?]*)\?subject_ID
```

It's basically the same as the one before but with the first bit captured instead of ignored.

Comment: Urg, bad internet is _awful_ for trying to edit answers. I'm going to add in online tests when I can make it work, but for now, you can just paste the code into [Regex101](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know. I had a _lot_ of trouble trying to edit this. Hotel WiFi just isn't reliable enough to do anything quickly, it seems.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good point. That was either a copy/paste error or a brain fart; take your pick.

Comment: No, I mean `[^/?]`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh, I see. Is there a specific reason why that's a benefit?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: I am also at a hotel now :) The WiFi here in the Tatra Mountains (Poland) is excellent. Casimir wants to optimize the backtracking  , and I'd use `[^/?#]*` then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew :'( You Europeans and your working internet. Also, I suspected as much, but the problem is that you'd also be matching `path`, `to`, and `subject_ID_etc`, unless I misunderstood what he's saying. Having the `\?` be outside of the character class reduces backtracking; it's not a valid path character  while all the characters in `subject_ID` are (at least, under Windows; I don't have a Unix system to test on ATM), it has to go less distance before failing to match. (Did that make sense? I hope so, but I doubt it.)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: What you say about backtracking is not true. The point is that to match the base part of the URL you may use `^[^?#]+` since the `?` starts a query string and `#` starts a bookmark. To find the last `/` you still need some backtracking. Depending on what the URLs look like, you could tune it with lazy or greedy type of the quantifier. Or use `split`.... Etc... I'd go with a non-regex here since it does what OP needs with no trouble.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh, I see. I misunderstood, then -- give me a moment to update my answer :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Remember how my internet is bad? The edit _just_ went through. Since the question didn't mention anything about anchors, and successfully parsing them would add an otherwise-irrelevant bit to the regex, I don't think it's worth thinking about here.